# nginx forward and rewrite url

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I run a simple wordpress website on `localhost:8888/website` with MAMP.
I want nginx to forward all traffic on `localhost:80`to `localhost:8888/website`

My nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
http {
  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade{
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
  }

 server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    rewrite / /website break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888/;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
```

}
}

This leads to `localhost/website/` but I want to forward to localhost:8888/website.

How come I'm not being forwarded to the right port and how can I correct this?

Comment: where is your `localhost:8888` served?

Comment: localhost served on 127.0.0.1